# JavaScript event for canvas resize

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

It appears that altering the dimensions of a canvas clears any drawing already done on that canvas.

Is there an event that fires on canvas resize, so I can hook it and redraw when it occurs?

Comment: In how many different places in your code are you re-sizing the canvas?  Couldn't you just call your redraw function after you've changed the size?

Comment: I don't want to assert that I'm the only one resizing a particular canvas.

Comment: I don't know if it would work for you, but I'm redrawing every frame using `requestAnimationFrame()` - I'm getting 60fps and I don't have to worry about redrawing when it's resized

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You usually don't want to strictly check for a resize event because they fire a lot when you do a dynamic resize, like $(window).resize in jQuery and as far I'm aware there is no native resize event on elements ([there is on window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onresize)). I would check it on an interval instead:

```
function onResize( element, callback ){
  var elementHeight = element.height,
      elementWidth = element.width;
  setInterval(function(){
      if( element.height !== elementHeight || element.width !== elementWidth ){
        elementHeight = element.height;
        elementWidth = element.width;
        callback();
      }
  }, 300);
}

var element = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
onResize( element, function(){ alert("Woo!"); } );
```

Comment: good enough, I suppose.  Using `setInterval()` for something that should be interactive makes me shudder every time though.

Comment: It is better to actually connect to the resize() event and (re-)start a redraw timer everytime it is fired. Only when the redraw timer runs out, the image is drawn.

Comment: does this actually work? MDN says only `window` fires a resize event

Comment: @oberhamsi Yes it works and it doesn't check for the resize event, it does a size comparison on an interval.

Comment: Doing logic in a loop "just in case" something happens is hacky code. I strongly recommend against using this kind of approach as it will always affect battery life adversely and increase the footprint of your app massively. Also, 300ms is an arbitrary number to pick, making this an asyncronous reponse to an event that might thereby make it unreliable. 300ms will also look slow/janky to the user.

Comment: @dudewad It’s quite an old answer but barring any sort of native resize events on elements, you have to poll the size of the element, unless of course you have the actual root cause for a resize, but that’s not always the case in a complex environment. This doesn’t particularly consume any resources since the callback only figured at the point of update and out of focus pages don’t fire events like they used to. Also these days someone should probably use requestAnimationFrame and debounce the event because you wouldn’t generally want to redraw while something is resizing.

Comment: I'm aware it was an old answer, I put the comment for any future novice developers that read it. Coding with intervals should be an absolute last resort, is my point.

Answer (score 15):

### Update 2020

Jemenake's answer looks good, but in general I would recommend loading in a library which provides `debounce` functionality, as that's what this is called.

For example with the lodash one, you can do `window.addEventListner('resize', _.debounce(onResize, 500)`. Note that there is a third argument where you can specify the behavior you want (e.g. `window.addEventListner('resize', _.debounce(onResize, 500, {leading: true, trailing true})`), although the default should be pretty good.

---

Kit Sunde's answer will do a lot of unnecessary work whilst the browser window is not resized. It is better to check whether the event got resized in response to a browser event and next ignore resize events for a given amount of time after which you do a check again (this will cause two checks after eachother in quick succession and the code could be improved to prevent this, but you get the idea probably).

```
 (function(){
      var doCheck = true;
      var check = function(){
           //do the check here and call some external event function or something.
      };
      window.addEventListener("resize",function(){
           if(doCheck){
                check();
                doCheck = false;
                setTimeout(function(){
                     doCheck = true;
                     check();
                },500)
           }
      });
 })();
```

*Please note, the code above was typed blindly and not checked.*

Answer (score 13):

David Mulder's answer is an improvement, but it looks like it will trigger after waiting *timeout* milliseconds after the *first* resize event. In other words, if more resizes happen before the timeout, it doesn't reset the timer. I was looking for the opposite; I wanted something which would wait a little bit of time to let the resize events stop, and then fire after a certain amount of time after the *last* one. The following code does that.

The ID of any currently-running timer will be in timer_id. So, whenever there's a resize, it checks to see if there's already a time running. If so, it cancels that one and starts a new one.

```
function setResizeHandler(callback, timeout) {
    var timer_id = undefined;
    window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
        if(timer_id != undefined) {
            clearTimeout(timer_id);
            timer_id = undefined;
        }
        timer_id = setTimeout(function() {
            timer_id = undefined;
            callback();
        }, timeout);
    });
}

function callback() {
    // Here's where you fire-after-resize code goes.
    alert("Got called!");
}
setResizeHandler(callback, 1500);
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver/ResizeObserver) ([caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=ResizeObserver)) in addition to the debounce logic mentioned in the other answers like [Jemenake's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30688151/5113030)?

For example:

```js
const pleasantText = 'There is a handle! Let\'s try relaxing while resizing the awesome canvas! ->';

onResize = (entries) => {
    document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = 
        `${pleasantText} <b>${entries[0].target.offsetWidth}x${entries[0].target.offsetHeight}</b>`;
};

const canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
const observer = new ResizeObserver(onResize);
observer.observe(canvas);
```

```css
body > div:first-of-type {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    user-select: none;
}

body > div:first-of-type div {
    display: grid;
    min-width: 12em;
    min-height: 6em;
    width: 16rem;
    height: 6rem;
    background: #ccc;
    overflow: auto;
    place-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    resize: both;
    grid-auto-columns: 20vw 1fr;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    padding: 0.4rem 0.8rem;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 0;
    min-height: 0;
    background: #ff9;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div>
        <span></span>
        <canvas></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any build-in events to detect new canvas dimensions, so I tried to find a workaround for two scenarios.

```
function onresize()
{
    // handle canvas resize event here
}

var _savedWidth = canvas.clientWidth;
var _savedHeight = canvas.clientHeight;
function isResized()
{
    if(_savedWidth != canvas.clientWidth || _savedHeight != canvas.clientHeight)
    {
        _savedWidth = canvas.clientWidth;
        _savedHeight = canvas.clientHeight;
        onresize();
    }
}

window.addEventListener("resize", isResized);

(new MutationObserver(function(mutations)
{
    if(mutations.length > 0) { isResized(); }
})).observe(canvas, { attributes : true, attributeFilter : ['style'] });
```

1. For detecting any JavaScript canvas.style changes, the MutationObserver API is good for. It doesn't detect a specific style property, but
   in this case it is sufficient to check if canvas.clientWidth and canvas.clientHeight has changed.
2. If the canvas size is declared in a style-tag with a percent unit, we have a problem to interpret the css selectors correctly (>, *, ::before, ...) by using JavaScript. I think in this case the best way is to set a window.resize handler and also check the canvas client size.

Answer (score -2):

save the canvas state as imageData and then redraw it after resizing

```
var imgDat=ctx.getImageData(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height)
```

after resize

```
ctx.putImageData(imgDat,0,0)
```

Comment: the issue is detecting when resizes have happened.