# Javascript Custom Resize Event

Tags: javascript, events, resize

I have a very simple question, or at least it seems that way.

I have a DIV element which will be resized at one moment. I want to be able to capture the resizing moment.

Something like this:

```
function myFunction(){
 alert('The DIV was resized');
}

divElement.addEventListener("resize", myFunction, false);
```

Does anyone know the answer?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [Javascript event for canvas resize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825447/javascript-event-for-canvas-resize).

Answer (score 3):

As of December 2011, there's no built-in event to detect when a div resizes, just when a window resizes.

Check out this related question: [Detecting when a div's height changes using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172821/detecting-when-a-divs-height-changes-using-jquery), and this plugin from the solution to that question: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/

> With jQuery resize event, you can now bind resize event handlers to
>   elements other than window, for super-awesome-resizing-greatness!
>
> **Why is a plugin needed for the resize event?**
>
> Long ago, the powers-that-be decided that the resize event would only
>   fire on the browser’s window object. Unfortunately, that means that if
>   you want to know when another element has resized, you need to
>   manually test its width and height, periodically, for changes. While
>   this plugin doesn’t do anything fancy internally to obviate that
>   approach, the interface it provides for binding the event is exactly
>   the same as what’s already there for window.
>
> For all elements, an internal polling loop is started which
>   periodically checks for element size changes and triggers the event
>   when appropriate. The polling loop runs only once the event is
>   actually bound somewhere, and is stopped when all resize events are
>   unbound.

**Sample Code**

```
// You know this one already, right?
$(window).resize(function(e){
  // do something when the window resizes
});

// Well, try this on for size!
$("#unicorns").resize(function(e){
  // do something when #unicorns element resizes
});

// And of course, you can still use .bind with namespaces!
$("span.rainbows").bind( "resize.rainbows", function(e){
  // do something when any span.rainbows element resizes
});
```

Comment: OP did not mention jQuery (wouldn't it be a duplicate of the question you linked to anyway?). Do you have a non-jQuery solution as well?

Comment: There is and there was always a method to determine for size changes without the inefficient `setTimeout` approach. Please check my answer to get more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this plugin - http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-resize/examples/resize/

There are various examples. Try resizing your window and see how elements inside container elements adjusted.

[Example with js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sgsqJ/4/)

In that resize() event is bound to an elements having class "test" and also to the window object and in resize callback of window object $('.test').resize() is called.

e.g.

```
$('#test_div').bind('resize', function(){
     console.log('resized');
});

$(window).resize(function(){
   $('#test_div').resize();
});
```

[See this](http://help.dottoro.com/ljorlllt.php)

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is to use a custom event system. You can find a pure javascript one here ( http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/09/custom-events-in-javascript/ )

After including his code, you can do something like this:

```
function myFunction(){
 alert('The DIV was resized');
}

div_elm = document.getElmentById('div-to-resize');
EventTarget.call(div_elm);
div_elm.addListener("resize", myFunction);
```

Then later, just add one line to wherever you are resizing the div.

```
div_elm.width += 100 //or however you are resizing your div
div_elm.fire("resize");
```

I think that should work for you.

EDIT:

If you are not the one coding the resizing, then my first thought is something like this:

```
var resizeScannerInterval_id = (function(div) {
    var width = div.offsetWidth;
    var height = div.offsetHeight;

    var interval_id = setInterval(function() {
        if( div.offsetWidth != width || div.offsetHeight != height )
            width = div.offsetWidth;
            height = div.offsetHeight;
            div.fire();
        }
    },250);

})(document.getElementById('div-id'))
```

Comment: What if you're not the one causing the resize?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very efficient method to determine if a element's size has been changed.

http://marcj.github.io/css-element-queries/

This library has a class ResizeSensor which can be used for resize detection. It uses a event-based approach, so it's damn fast and doesn't waste CPU time.

Please do **not use** the jQuery onresize plugin as it uses `setTimeout()` loop to check for changes. THIS IS INCREDIBLY SLOW AND NOT ACCURATE.