# canvas element resizing using window event

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, canvas

I am using typescript to draw canvas element. I would like to make my canvas element responsive to the screen size. So that I can match the canvas size to the parent div element.

I have tried to use this **removing the size in canvas and providing it in .css**. But this doesn't help because I have two fixed elements. I have found this solution which is 8 years old [canvas resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825447/javascript-event-for-canvas-resize).

How can I approach this problem ? The answer which I have posted distortes the image quality way too much. Is there any other approach ?

```js
export class bar {

  private canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;
  private ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
  private width_canvas: number;
  private height_canvas: number;

  constructor(canvas: HTMLCanvasElement) {
    this.canvas = < HTMLCanvasElement > canvas;

    this.ctx = < CanvasRenderingContext2D > canvas.getContext('2d');

    this.width_canvas = this.canvas.width;
    this.height_canvas = this.canvas.height;

    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.draw());
  };

  draw() {

      let wid_bar: number = this.width_canvas - 400;
      this.value.forEach((val, idx) => {

          // draw bar background
          this.ctx.save();
          this.ctx.beginPath();
          this.ctx.rect(200, (idx * (80)), wid_bar, 30);
          this.ctx.fillStyle = yellow;
          this.ctx.fill();
          window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.draw());
        };
      }
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1200" height="200"> This does not work </canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Its not really clear what your trying to do.  Canvas is a raster image, as such not great for responsive use, you would need to re-draw on every resize.  SVG's on the other hand are vector based and are ideal for responsive layouts.  So maybe that might be an idea...

Answer (score 2):

try (if you use CSS width only without redrawing then picture it will lose quality) instead input value read screen size

```js
function change(inp) {
  can.width = inp.value;
  can.height = inp.value/4;
  draw(can, [5,10,15,20])
}

function draw(canvas,value) {
  let ctx = can.getContext('2d');
  let wid_bar = canvas.width - 400;
  value.forEach((val, idx) => {
      // draw bar background
      ctx.save();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(200, idx * 80, wid_bar, 30);
      ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
      ctx.fill();
  });
}

change(audio);
```

```css
canvas { background: black; }
```

```html
<input id="audio" type="range" min="100" max="600" oninput="change(this)" value=150 /><br>

<canvas id="can"></canvas>
```

Comment: I have fixed values for two of the rectangle though. does it make any difference to this ? for the bar I am using `canvas.width and canvas.height`

Comment: @cantona_7 if this not help then upate you question and put your code html/css/js

Comment: Kielczewski..,you mean I should add another function to it ?