# responsive canvas element with typescript

Tags: html, typescript, canvas

The question has duplicate here [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56000611/canvas-element-resizing-using-window-event/56003477?noredirect=1#comment98667080_56003477).Further there are no proper solution for canvas resize. I have tried few solutions which didn't help much. I would like to have resize the canvas element with JavaScript not with `css property`. I have the following code. Been stuck here for days. How can I proceed forward ?

```js
export class bar {

  private canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;
  private ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
  private width_canvas: number;
  private height_canvas: number;

  constructor(canvas: HTMLCanvasElement) {
    this.canvas = < HTMLCanvasElement > canvas;

    this.ctx = < CanvasRenderingContext2D > canvas.getContext('2d');

    this.width_canvas = this.canvas.width;
    this.height_canvas = this.canvas.height;

    if (this.width_canvas !== innerWidth || this.height_canvas !== innerHeight) {
      this.width_canvas = innerWidth; // resize canvas
      this.height_canvas = innerHeight;
    } else {
      this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this._w_canvas, this._h_canvas); // clear if not resized
    };

    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.draw());
  };

  draw() {

      let wid_bar: number = this.width_canvas - 400;
      this.value.forEach((val, idx) => {

          // draw bar background
          this.ctx.save();
          this.ctx.beginPath();
          this.ctx.rect(200, (idx * (80)), wid_bar, 30);
          this.ctx.fillStyle = yellow;
          this.ctx.fill();
          window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.draw());
        };
      }
```

Comment: If you already asked the same question, why did you ask it again? Also you are not explaining at all what part of the code is giving you trouble or not working as you intend.

Comment: @Esko I didn't get the answer and also I forgot to mention about typescript. There are no errors as well no change. If i resize the screen the canvas element remains the same.

Comment: @Esko for this problem, there are no proper solution available yet. so I thought of posting it to get more attention

Comment: Possible duplicate of [canvas element resizing using window event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56000611/canvas-element-resizing-using-window-event)

Comment: @Cerberus even I have mentioned it already.

Answer (score 0):

This will be another alternative answer with JS/TS not with `css property`.
But this matches the width of thw window. Not the parent width.

```js
if (this.width_canvas !== innerWidth || this.height_canvas !== innerHeight) {
  this.width_canvas = innerWidth; // resize canvas
  this.height_canvas = innerHeight;
} else {
  this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
};
```

In order to match the parent div width. Follow the code below

```js
this.canvas.width = this.parent.offsetWidth;
this.width_canvas = this.canvas.width;
this.parent = this.canvas.parentNode;

if (this.width_canvas !== this.parent.offsetWidth) {
  // do whatever you need
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a potential solution. In my code, I created a canvas inside of a div (which had the correct relative size). I then used the following code to create and resize the canvas. You can call the resizeCanvas() function anytime the screen resizes.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    this.doc = document.getElementById("placeToInsertCanvas");
    if (this.doc) {
        this.doc.appendChild(this.canvas);
        this.resizeCanvas();
    }
}

public resizeCanvas() {
    this.canvas.width = this.doc.clientWidth;
    this.canvas.height = this.doc.clientHeight;
}
```